# Check button for class and if it has a certain class create a 'done' div

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, html

I am new to Jquery. I have an upload form that when something is uploaded the upload-button changes class from:

```
<a class="upload-button upload buy" id="upload-button"><span>Upload a document</span></a>
```

To:

```
<a class="upload-button buy white" id="upload-button"><span>Upload a document</span></a>
```

I have tried to write a function that adds a div called 'done' if a file has already been uploaded(the class in the button has changed).

Here is what I have got so far:

```
$('a#upload-button').ready(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('white')) {
                $('#three')
                    .append('<div class="done rotateone wiggler"></div>')
                    .addClass('grey');
        }
        })
```

I am not sure why it is not working. Please could somebody help?

Comment: not working could mean anything, please specify what you mean by "not working"

Comment: Sorry. The div i am adding for when my if statement is valid is not being created and neither is the class i am adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do (if you want to check if a button has a class when the page is loaded, otherwise just take the `if` part and put it where you need it

```
//this is a shorthand methot for $(document).ready() 
//you should use this to wait for the dom to load
$(function(){
 //if the link has the class
  if($('a#upload-button').hasClass('white')){
     //append the button
     $('#three')
        .append('<div class="done rotateone wiggler"></div>')
        .addClass('grey');
  }
});
```

EDIT - you should modify your script

```
function verifyFileUploadState(up) {
    if ($(".file-title").length == 0) {
        $("#upload-button span").html("Upload a document");
        $("#upload-button").addClass("upload");
        $("#upload-button").removeClass("white");
    } else {
        $("#upload-button span").html("Upload another document");
        $("#upload-button").removeClass("upload");
        $("#upload-button").addClass("white");
         $('#three')
            .append('<div class="done rotateone wiggler"></div>')
            .addClass('grey');
    }
    up.refresh();
}
```

Comment: how would i edit this so that as soon as the button changed class it would append the div and change its class?

Comment: @MarkBlythe what is that trigger a change of class?It must be some javascript code

Comment: Do you mean the script that triggers the button change?
The code for that is here:
`function verifyFileUploadState(up) {
    if ($(".file-title").length == 0) {
        $("#upload-button span").html("Upload a document");
        $("#upload-button").addClass("upload");
        $("#upload-button").removeClass("white");
    }
    else {
        $("#upload-button span").html("Upload another document");
        $("#upload-button").removeClass("upload");
        $("#upload-button").addClass("white");
    }

    up.refresh();
}`